# Keep getting Inconsistent accessibility error C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know that this question has been raised and answered on this site. But the solutions are not working for me. I keep getting this error although i am setting my object class to public.

this is my code:

```
public Shipment shipment;
public CreateMultipleShipments(Shipment shpmnt)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    shipment = new Shipment();
    this.shipment = shpmnt;
    txtBarcode0.Text = shipment.Barcode;
    txtShpmntNr0.Text = shipment.Barcode2;
    txtWeight0.Text = Convert.ToString(shipment.Weight);
    txtVolume0.Text = Convert.ToString(shipment.Volume);
}
```

and this is the class i have created:

```
 class Shipment
    {
        public int SendingID { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string Barcode2 { get; set; }
        public string PickupType { get; set; }
        public int PickupAdrID { get; set; }
        public string PickupCustomer { get; set; }
        public string PickupAlias { get; set; }
        public string PickupAttention { get; set; }
        public int PickupRouteID { get; set; }
        public string PickupRoutePart { get; set; }
        public DateTime PickupDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime PWindowFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime PWindowTo { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryType { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryAdrID { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryCustomer { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryAlias { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryAttention { get; set; }
        public int DeliveryRouteID { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryRoutePart { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DWindowFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DWindowTo { get; set; }
        public string Coli { get; set; }
        public double Weight { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string ServiceType { get; set; }
        public int KM { get; set; }

        public Shipment()
        {

        }
    }
```

When i set my Shipment initialization to public i get Inconsistent accessibility error on these two lines:

```
public Shipment shipment;
public CreateMultipleShipments(Shipment shpmnt)
```

I cant seem to find a solution for this problem. hope you guys are able to help me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `Shipment` should be declared as `public`. the default  when you  don't specify  any modifier  is internal and here is the inconsistency
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) 
`Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.`

```
public class Shipment {
    public int SendingID { get; set; }
    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string Barcode2 { get; set; } 
    // ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add no modifier to your class the default modifier is internal.

So your Shipment class is internal which is inconsistent with the other public modifiers.

Add the public modifier to your Shipment class to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are just declaring your class as:

```
class Shipment
```

By default when you exclude an accessibility modifier then it defaults to `internal`. Please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for an explanation of access modifiers.

To avoid this you should specify the access modifier that you require in your case `public` e.g.

```
public class Shipment
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.